# how to prevent arrayindexoutofbound exception even ther no data? [sqlite android]

Tags: java, android

first i create data only.
second i no add any data to keep table empty
then i call this comment

```
Cursor cursor = sqlite.fetchdata(2, DatabaseHelper.TABLE_COMMENT);
String getcontent = cursor.getString(0);
```

it sure that will gave me exception.

so my question is how to get the string even there is empty table also? because my application by default is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a check after the first line.

```
if(cursor!=null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    //Your computation here
}
```

or put the statement in a try catch block to handle the exception.

```
String getcontent = "";
        try {
            getcontent = cursor.getString(0);
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: should i fetchdata first then only check or check first only fetch?

Comment: if getInt(2); also ... && cursor.moveToFirst()?